# How to automatically periodically rebuild AWS Elastic BeanStalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am looking for a way to trigger re-build of the Elastic Beanstalk back-end every day at night. Right now I am doing it manually through the AWS console.

How can a Lambda (?) be set up to do the same automatically?

Comment: Are you willing to use AWS CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would create a Lambda function, in whatever language you choose, that uses the AWS SDK for that language. The Lambda function would call the Elastic Beanstalk API to trigger an environment rebuild.

For example if you wrote the Lambda function in Python, you would use the AWS SDK for Python (aka Boto3) and call `rebuild_environment()` method on the [ElasticBeanstalk client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.rebuild_environment).

You would create an IAM role for the Lambda function, and assign the appropriate permissions to that IAM role to allow it to rebuild your ElasticBeanstalk environment.

Finally, you would [schedule the Lambda function to run every night](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduledevents-example.html) via a Cron expression.